# Updating multiple rows using Yii's updateAll()

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to update multiple rows in Yii:

```
$list = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

foreach($list as $id) {
    $query = "UPDATE products SET photos=crawler.photos, status=crawler.status WHERE id=crawler.product_id AND crawler.product_id=$id;";
}
```

I'm new to Yii. Basically, I want to update rows from table `products` with the values from table `scrape` (using specific `id`, which are coming from `$list`). But not with `foreach()`, but with `updateAll()`.

Comment: You have a result to apply to all rows or distinct row to update one by one? From your foreach seems you have several distinct values...

Comment: $item->id is the primary key for Products row?

Comment: In the way you  have posted the question seems you want assign to several Products row the same crawler .* values ... .. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think should be somethings like this

```
public function actionMyProductsUpdate($id)
{
    foreach ($queue as $item) {
        $myUpdate = "UPDATE products as a join crawler as b 
        on  (  a.id=b.product_id  and b.product_id= $item->id)
        SET a.photos=b.photos, a.status=b.status;";
         \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($myUpdate)->execute();    
    }

}
```

version 2

```
public function actionMyProductsUpdate($id)
{

        $myUpdate = "UPDATE products as a join crawler as b 
        on  (  a.id=b.product_id  and b.product_id in  $list )
        SET a.photos=b.photos, a.status=b.status;";
         \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($myUpdate)->execute();    


}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! And last think, is it possible to be without `foreach()`, but one whole query? Since I'm talking about 100,000 IDs daily. Isn't `updateAll()` for this? Thanks! P.S. like "one query update".

Comment: The item list from where is ?

Comment: Yes, the item list will have daily 100,000 id's.

Comment: If my answer is useful plase rate it as useful too.

Comment: I still don't have enough reputation, but when I do, I'll rate it. And one more thing, can I limit to `1` the `a.id=b.product_id`, since there are multiple `b.product_id` in `crawler`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Active directory pattern. Good to write mode.

```
$movies_updated = SomeModel::updateAll([
     'language' => 'pl',
     'age' => 3,
], ['id' => 1]); # condition
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such. See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#updateAll()-detail

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I happened across it whilst researching something a little more complex. If I'm understanding the intention correctly, this should work:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand(
    "UPDATE products p, crawler c
        SET p.photos = c.photos, p.status = c.status
        WHERE p.id = c.product_id;"
            )->execute();
```

(I prefer the direct join syntax, particularly where the join is being used in an update.)